# Personalisation Builder - associating previous session basket with next session when first session is anonymous

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

is it possible to associate an anonymous visitor's abandoned basket in one session to their next logged-in/registered/form submit session? Do we just need an automation joining uuids to subscriber key to join it all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends if that anonymous user has the same cookie like the last time he visits the website (and has used the login feature). If the user uses a different browser, has an Ad-Blocker, a different device or deletes the cookie ........ then you cannot identify that user... therefore impossible

UNLESS

that anonymous user logs in and you can determine which user this was (with a known cookie user_id)...then you could determine which "email" has logged in when you would query the igoprofiles table of the marketing cloud and obtain that "email" value. With these details of the setUserInfo call which has done in the past you could alter the tracking calls and would know which basket that user had. Then you actually know that this cookie-id is a specific user in the `IGO_PROFILES` table.

But if you do not have a known user, i believe that this will be quite tricky... maybe Lukas Lunow has more to offer... but idk